# Changing style of latex description lists

Tags: latex

This should be an easy question for someone out there. I have a description list

```
\begin{description}
\item[Name:]  Halpo
\item[Email Address:] halpo@users.mysite.com
\item[Address:]  1234 Ivy Ln \\ Springfield, USA
\end{description}
```

It comes back as

> **Name:** Halpo
>
> **Email Address:** halpoe@users.mysite.com
>
> **Address:** 1234 Ivy Ln
>
> ```
>  Springfield, USA
> ```

This is for an official document that has style requirements.  The First thing is how do I turn off the bold? second how do I have all the text line up with the item labels and still be left justified?

Comment: Belongs on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tex (but is too old to migrate).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you `\usepackage{enumitem}` you may get what you like:

```
\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm,font=\normalfont]
\item[Name:]  Halpo
\item[Email Address:] halpo@users.mysite.com
\item[Address:]  1234 Ivy Ln \\ Springfield, USA
\end{description}
```

Results in:

[image: Results]

Check [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/) for full package documentation.

Comment: It would be nice if the `leftmargin` parameter could be automatic. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 25):

The formatting of description labels is controlled by the command `\descriptionlabel`.  Here's an example of changing to italics, no bold:

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textit{#1}}
```

To change the formatting of the label to something else, change the `\textit{#1}` part above.

*EDIT 2017-01-24*: My original example used `\emph`, but as @ebo pointed out, it is better to use `\textit` for this situation because this is a case of changing the text style, not emphasizing text.

Comment: be aware that nested uses of  `\emph` will toggle between italics and Roman.

Comment: @SeanAllred Indeed, instead of `\emph{#1}` (that states you want to *emphasize* the text), one should use `\textit{#1}` (that says you want the text to be printed with italicized font).

Comment: @ebo You make a very good point. I will indicate this in the answer, for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 7):

Geoff - you can set these parameters for all lists (so that it's automatic) using this code:

```
\setlist[description]{style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm}
```

Apologies, I don't have enough rep to reply to your comment, hence the separate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the note. What I meant was for the `3cm` to be computed automatically. This is helpful though.

Comment: Yes, it was replying to Geoff's comment above (the accepted answer). It's for the _enumitem_ package: `\usepackage{enumitem}`. See [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741350/713980) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

For a hack, do `\item[\rm Name:]`.